# In VS Code, is it possible to disable code unfolding when the user clicks the blank area preceding the "..."?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, folding

Excluding keyboard shortcuts, folded regions in VSCode can be unfolded by clicking on one of three places:

1. [+] button in the gutter area
2. The "..." immediately preceding the last character of the first line of code in that region
3. Anywhere in the blank area to the right of the "..."

Is it possible to write an extension that disables the last one? I tend to randomly click around in my code while I'm thinking which leads to unintentionally unfolding regions of code and loosing my spot.

Comment: The API methods for folding and unfolding exists, but I don't think there's anything for seeing whether your mouse is within a folded area itself (The VSCode Vim extension has been needing this for the cursor). I feel like you might end up reimplementing folding if you go along this route. If I were you I would open an issue on VSCode issues asking for this feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be useful, coming in v1.43: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_43.md#folding

> **Folding**
>
> There's a new setting that controls what happens when you click in the
>   empty space behind a folded line (after the ...):
>
> `"editor.unfoldOnClickAfterEndOfLine": true.`
>
> By default the setting is turned off

.